# Login to web server with Google Sign-in

Tags: download, httpclient, google-signin

I'm connecting to a 3rd party web server from an HTTP client (Java or Dart - Android app) to download some resources (XML or IMG files) that belong to the current user on that server. This site requires login with Google Sing-In. I have everything set up in my Android app to login the user with Google, I obtained their authorization idToken. But how do actually use it in HTTP GET or POST methods to download the protected resources?

With BASIC authentication it's easy - just set HTTP 'Authorization' header correctly ("Basic " + user:password encoded as base64), call GET, and I download the desired resource. But I cannot find any information on how to do this with Google Sing-In. Do I send the idToken I received from Google in some headers? What other magic is needed?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)? I guess the server you're trying to talk to has a similar implementation.

Comment: Also [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth).

Answer (score 3):

Adding a Java code snippet, hope it helps:

```
// (Receive authCode via HTTPS POST)


if (request.getHeader('X-Requested-With') == null) {
  // Without the `X-Requested-With` header, this request could be forged. Aborts.
}

// Set path to the Web application client_secret_*.json file you downloaded from the
// Google API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
// You can also find your Web application client ID and client secret from the
// console and specify them directly when you create the GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest
// object.
String CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = "/path/to/client_secret.json";

// Exchange auth code for access token
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
    GoogleClientSecrets.load(
        JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), new FileReader(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE));
GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse =
          new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
              new NetHttpTransport(),
              JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
              "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
              clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId(),
              clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret(),
              authCode,
              REDIRECT_URI)  // Specify the same redirect URI that you use with your web
                             // app. If you don't have a web version of your app, you can
                             // specify an empty string.
              .execute();

String accessToken = tokenResponse.getAccessToken();

// Use access token to call API
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
Drive drive =
    new Drive.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential)
        .setApplicationName("Auth Code Exchange Demo")
        .build();
File file = drive.files().get("appfolder").execute();

// Get profile info from ID token
GoogleIdToken idToken = tokenResponse.parseIdToken();
GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();
String userId = payload.getSubject();  // Use this value as a key to identify a user.
String email = payload.getEmail();
boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
String name = (String) payload.get("name");
String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
String locale = (String) payload.get("locale");
String familyName = (String) payload.get("family_name");
String givenName = (String) payload.get("given_name");
```

For detailed info, find all the required steps and references at: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow#step_1_create_a_client_id_and_client_secret

Comment: Thank you! I'm traveling now so cannot test it immediately. I'll award the points by accepting the answer after I'm able to test, unless the system does it automatically for me after a while. Appreciate very much your help.

Comment: Unfortunately upon closer inspection this answer does not help me much. It only gives me access to Google Drive API and app folder, something I already do in another app (written in Java) without any problem. The task I'm facing is logging in to a 3rd party web site - not Google Drive, but a site created by another company, which requires login with Google... I do get GoogleCredential with accessToken, but don't know what to do with that, how to tell this _other_ web site that the correct Google account is logged in, to grant it the required access.

Comment: You need to pass in the credentials and access parameters to log in with Google along with the POST request on your 3rd party app.

Comment: Thank you! I still don't understand all the details, but maybe I approached the problem incorrectly. It seems that the web site I had in mind indeed is storing files in the user's Google Drive, in the 3rd party app private folder. So I won't have any way to access it from my app, no matter what I do.

Comment: Welcome. You can try to find out more about the requirement. Once the problem statement is sorted, answer can be approached directly. Accessing a folder related to an app, depends on access permission rights. If you have authority to edit the permissions (even through code), you can see the content.

Comment: I actually solved the problem in another way: when Google login page is sent instead of the XML file I expected, show that page in a local WebView, after the user has logged in - save the cookies from WebView control and set them in Java or Dart http client as request cookie header, re-send the request for my XML resource - all works fine.

Comment: Of course, the "solution" with WebView control is considered unsafe, unsupported and strongly discouraged. Nobody knows how to do this correctly, not even people who AppAuth solution on GitHub (https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/issues/386#issuecomment-411247953). The problem remains unsolved.